# PlaceHolders in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf template and I want to put the property of an object as a 
placeholder, but I see `${menu.name}`, instead.

```
<form id="menuFormId" action="#" th:action="@{/menu/save}" th:object="${menu}" method="post">

  <input type="text" placeholder="${menu.name}" disabled="disabled" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prefix every attribute Thymeleaf should process with a `th` (since you did this for the action above I am sure that you are using the namespace `th` for Thymeleaf).
So your placeholder has to be defined as `th:placeholder="${menu.name}"`.